# can't find H2 installtion directory in Ubuntu

Tags: h2

I install H2 plugin using this link https://kenai.com/projects/nbh2/pages/Install . But When I
 want to start, it first tells me to specify the H2 installation directory. Now I can't find the directory where I installed it. I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find / -name h2` to find where H2 is installed.